# Entrypoint undefined = index.html using HtmlWebpackPlugin

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using Webpack 4 and I'm creating the config file, when trying to use the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` it got this on the console: `Entrypoint undefined = index.html`, it opens the browser and the HTML does appear but I'm getting this weird message on the console, how to solve this?

That is how my config file looks like:

```
'use strict'

const webpack = require('webpack')
const { join, resolve } = require('path')

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development', // dev
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map', // dev
  entry: join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')
    }),

    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // dev
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin() // dev
  ]
}
```

Comment: show your directory structure where is your index.js? and where is your index.html ? This would be helpful in debugging the issue

Comment: The `index.js` is inside the `src` folder. The `index.html` is inside the `public` folder. There's nothing more than that. The `Webpack` config is in the root folder and the `.babelrc` with `{ "presets": ["env", "react"] }`.

Answer (score 7):

Try this; you might be making wrong template path :

```
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: resolve(__dirname, 'src/public', 'index.html'),
        filename: './index.html'
      }),
```

If public is in src folder this should work It's my assumption.
Let me know if the issue still persists.

Comment: You got that wrong, the `src` is where the components are at, the `public` is where the static files are like the `index.html`. I noticed that this message appears only on the `webpack-dev-server` and not only for me but for a lot of people including the tutorials on Youtube, it seems to be harmeless and I could get rid of that by using `stats: { children: false }`

Comment: Glad to hear this. Finally it is fixed.

Comment: @xahovuzu how did you fix it? Please post an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @xahovuzu Did you ever resolve this?  It's been bugging me forever and I can't find a fix anywhere.

Comment: @xahovuzu this does not only happen on web dev server, It happens for me when i run webpack --mode production

Comment: this is still broken for me. does anyone know how to fix it? The error is not harmless - I can't find the generated file anywhere (it doesn't seem to make one).

Comment: Using stats is not a solution, `stats { chidden: false }` because this only hide plugins info. 

read about it here [webpack stats](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/)

Comment: I found some working solution. Check the answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013133/entrypoint-undefined-index-html-using-htmlwebpackplugin/57123167#57123167).

Answer (score 5):

According to the creators of `HtmlWebpackPlugin` it's just a meaningless log message and an ignorable cosmetic issue. See [this comment](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/895#issuecomment-379006202) on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with the extension of the template firing an unwanted loader. If the extension of the template is changed to any other the plugin will work.

If you're using the default webpack template system ([EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs), as of webpack 4) it makes sense to use `ejs` because the template isn't valid `html` anymore:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    // it works without 'path.resolve()'. No need for 'filename', defaults to 'index.html'
    template: "./public/index.ejs",
}),
```

webpack considers by default that the template is EJS and will automatically process it with the proper loader. If you use any other template system you will have to add the corresponding loader. More info on [official documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md).

Comment: This didn't get rid of the undefined message for me.

Answer (score 0):

```json
plugins: [
      ...
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        title: '...',
        template: path.resolve(folderSrc, 'index.html'),
        filename: 'index.html',
        hash: true
      })
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Error got fixed in mine by adding this in webpack.config.js :

```
    stats: { children: false }, //to fix the error-Entrypoint undefined=index.html  
      plugins:[  
          new HtmlWebpackPlugin({  
             template: './index.html'  
          })  
      ]
```