# npm start showing index.html not defined eventhough index.html present

Tags: node.js, flutter, webrtc

I am trying to implement a voip call in flutter, got a sample code from github https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc-server, the server is done in node js which is new to me, I could install node js and could able to start with npm start, but showing an issue like below

```
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.59 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/index.js] 166 bytes {main} [built]
    + 331 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html] 370 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 528 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

The page is loading but saying the site cannot be reached.

Comment: did you install all the packages required ?
1. npm install 
2. npm start

Comment: yes, i got the server node js project from github, installed node js first, then did npm install and then npm start.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013133/entrypoint-undefined-index-html-using-htmlwebpackplugin